# KeyStore vs KeyChain

Tags: android, encryption, android-keystore

I have an app that generates a key for encryption/decryption and it is working just fine. I store my key in KeyStore and IV as first 12B in encrypted file saved on external storage. When I want to decrypt the file, I get the file from external storage (hence I get IV) and key from KeyStore, and I am able to get original content. My second application App2 can access file in external storage (hence it can get IV), but it can't get key from App1 KeyStore. I was reading about KeyChain and it says in official documentation it is not app private (Use the KeyChain API when you want system-wide credentials). Can I somehow store my key in this KeyChain or somewhere else so my App2 can get it (with some user approval or something similar). Here is the code I used to create and store key in App1.

```
 private static SecretKey createAndStoreKey() {
        KeyGenerator keyGen;
        try {
            // Generate 256-bit key
            keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, KEY_STORE_NAME);

            final KeyGenParameterSpec keyGenParameterSpec = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(KEY_ALIAS,
                    KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                    .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
                    .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
                    .build();

            keyGen.init(keyGenParameterSpec);

            SecretKey secretKey = keyGen.generateKey();
            if(secretKey != null)
                return secretKey;
            else
                return null;
        }
        catch (NoSuchProviderException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Thank you all for the help.

Comment: I think you're looking for [Content Providers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) in order to share data between your applications securely

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is my task requires using KeyStore and KeyChain. I have an implementation with content provider, but as I said I need to investigate these other options :S

Comment: I **think** you should be able to share the `Keystore`'s access by defining a [sharedUserId](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#uid) in your apps manifest (you need also to sign the apps with the same certificate). But I haven't tried it and tbh it doesn't seem the best solution.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. Do you know anything about storing keys in KeyChain, is it possible at all?

Comment: No problem! And i'm sorry but no, I have no experience using KeyChain in Android so I can't answer that :\

Comment: @Mediha Were you able to find a way to store the key in Keychain? I am having the same use case

Comment: What is the difference between keychain and keystore

Comment: @Alvin567 Check the answer from Anice here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56130060/4153947, it should address your question.

Answer (score 21):

> Use the KeyChain API when you want system-wide credentials. When an app requests the use of any credential through the KeyChain API, users get to choose, through a system-provided UI, which of the installed credentials an app can access. This allows several apps to use the same set of credentials with user consent.
>
> Use the Android Keystore provider to let an individual app store its
>   own credentials that only the app itself can access. This provides a
>   way for apps to manage credentials that are usable only by itself
>   while providing the same security benefits that the KeyChain API
>   provides for system-wide credentials. This method requires no user
>   interaction to select the credentials.
>   [refrence](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore)